# how to iterate json data in html using jquery in tree view structure node

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui

I want to iterate JSON data in a tree view structure. For first level I am only able to iterate json value and for second third level failed to iterate the data next next level of data inside the parent array.

The way of declaring my key/value pairs in JSON may also be an issue because I am using the same '*title*' keyword.

#### JSON

```
{  
           "category":[        
               {  
                 "title":"Customer Satisfaction", // first levl
                 "items":[  
                    {  
                       "title":"Bulletins", // second level
                       "id":"nnanet:category/customer-satisfaction/bulletins"
                    },
                    {  
                       "title":"Consumer Affairs", // second level
                       "id":"nnanet:category/customer-satisfaction/consumer-affairs"
                    },
                    {  
                       "title":"Loyalty",
                       "id":"nnanet:category/customer-satisfaction/loyalty"
                    },
                    {  
                       "title":"Reference Guide",
                       "id":"nnanet:category/customer-satisfaction/reference-guide"
                    },
                    {  
                       "title":"TOI",
                       "id":"nnanet:category/customer-satisfaction/toi"
                    }
                 ]
              },
              {  
                 "title":"Accessories",
                 "id":"nnanet:category/accessories"
              },
              {  
                 "title":"Certified Pre-Owned",
                 "id":"nnanet:category/certified-pre-owned"
              }

           ]
        }
```

#### HTML

```
<div id="all-id">
    <ul class="tree"></ul> // appending html code and json code inside this //
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../js/internal/json/documentListing.json',
    datatype: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    cache: 'false',
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data.category, function(index, value) {
            console.log("Title :" + value.title + "," + "ID :" + value.id);
            var treeViewdata = "<li> <a href='#'>" + items.title + "</a> <ul> <li> <a href='#'>" +
                value.title + "</a> </ul> </li> </li>";
            $(treeViewdata).appendTo(".tree");
        });
    }
});
```

`value.title` is the first level of data showing and `items.title` is the second level of data to iterate. Here I am only getting issue and the condition is failing.

Comment: This is because the category array contains one item with a title "Customer Satisfaction" and that item contains a collection called items. So the bulk of those titles are nested under the first item

Comment: if i use separate keyword it will work you are saying

Comment: I guess the question is: should all titles (Bulletins onwards) be children of  the Customer Satisfaction title, or should they all be one collection? Noticed the questions been reformatted, makes more sense now

Comment: this may help: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082928/convert-json-to-html-tree)

Comment: no tried but not yet resolved

Answer (score 0):

I used the link I supplied you in the comments along with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13347251/4045532.

The key thing is the use of this recursive method:

```
function json2html(json) {
var i, ret = document.createElement('ul'), li;
for( i in json) {
    li = ret.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i+": "));
    if( typeof json[i] === "object") li.appendChild(json2html(json[i]));
    else li.firstChild.nodeValue += json[i];
}
return ret;
```

}

The output can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/xkL03obg/

It's just one example of how you could achieve this. Hope it helps